How to display the Enter key on the mobile keyboard for an ion-input in Ionic?
enter image description here
 <ion-input
         
      placeholder="Amount"
         (ionFocus)="clear('discountAmt')"
        class="input-field right-align"
        [(ngModel)]="discountAmt"
        (ngModelChange)="updateDiscountPercent()"
          type="text" 
          (ionInput)="validateInput($event)"
        (keydown.Enter)="transformdiscountAmount($event)"         
        
      >
        <p slot="end"></p>
      </ion-input>

I'm using Ionic and have an ion-input element, but when the mobile keyboard appears, it does not show the Enter key. Instead, it shows a Next or Done button.
How can I configure the keyboard to display the Enter key for an ion-input?

add enterkeyhint attribute on your ion-input tag. enterkeyhint="enter". Check Docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input#enterkeyhint
